# How to extract and separate one jar file into several?

Tags: java, build, executable, executable-jar

Say I have a .jar file **Test.jar** which which includes **a.jar** and **b.jar** as the dependency.

I want to achieve following:

- make new jar, so that it doesn't contain a.jar and b.jar and while
  launching from command line, pass them as arguments. *i.e. java -jar
  Test.jar -cp "a.jar; b.jar"*

Comment: Do you want to do this manually or automatically?

Comment: @TheJavaGuy-IvanMilosavljević manually

Comment: Answer from @kofman seems right. I'd just add that jar files are just zip files, so any tool which can manipulate zip files can help you.

Comment: @TheJavaGuy-IvanMilosavljević that info does not help. How to move a part of jar content out so that original jar could automatically read it too when needed?

Answer (score 1):

You could extract your Test.jar into one directory, move the a.jar and b.jar out to a separate directory and then repack the Test.jar back:

```
jar x Test.jar
mv <path to a.jar> <new path>
.. - do same for b.jar
jar cf Test.jar -C <classes dir>
```